# Loading a file programmatically into iBooks

Tags: objective-c, ios, ibooks

I'm not sure why this code isn't working. Any ideas? iBooks opens, but nothing is presented.

```
NSString *fileToOpen = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"ibooks"]; 
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-books:%@", fileToOpen];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itms-books:` URL scheme is for links to the iBookstore. If you have a PDF or ePub file you want to allow the user to open in iBooks, look into [`QLPreviewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304).

Comment: This is correct, `QLPreviewController` is the way to go. Even if itms-books: supported local paths, iBooks doesn't have visibility into your sandbox. Only the system APIs can manage the transfer of a file from your app into iBooks.